# Mac,failed to import p12 file

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain

I've create self-signed certificate files.

First，created xxx.key file with password,then use xxx.key file to export xxx.p12 file without password.

How can I import p12 via keychain access app,since the app ask password to import p12,but the password used to create xxx.key file won't work.

the export p12 command is like this:

pkcs12 -export -out ./p12/xxxx.p12 -inkey ./keys/xxxx.KEY -in certificates/xxxx.CRT -certfile ../CA/xxxx.CRT

When import p12 enter the password used to create xxx.key file or enter nothing either would not success.

Answer (score 0):

After using the command below to regenerate p12 file and setting the export password,the keychain access app can import the p12 file now when enter the export password.

pkcs12 -export -out ./p12/xxxx.p12 -inkey ./keys/xxxx.KEY -in certificates/xxxx.CRT -certfile ../CA/xxxx.CRT